# Microsoft Deployment Toolkit setting SystemAutoLogon registry key when deploying upgraded OS

Tags: mdt

I'm trying to deploy images via MDT that have been upgraded via the MDT "Standard Client Upgrade" task sequence. My images started as Win10 v1607 images and are updated to v1703 and then captured.

When I go to deploy the captured images, I'll get a popup on first login that c:\LTIBootstrap.vbs can't be found. Digging, I discovered that after the OS is installed and the PC restarts, the MDT task sequence continues running as **the SYSTEM account** . This is bizarre as it typically runs as the built-in Administrator account.

For some reason, even though the unattend.xml file contains the usual AutoAdminLogon entries, a registry key at

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SystemAutoLogon
```

is being created and set to 1 during the deployment. (I discovered this by comparing the registries at the end of deployment.) This key is not present in the captured image. **This key does not get created if I deploy an image that is manually updated to v1703 (via Windows Update instead of MDT).**

Any ideas on why the unattend.xml could be ignored or what would cause SystemAutoLogon to get created and set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

The MDT Upgrade task sequence invokes the upgrade with the command line /postoobe option pointing to setupcomplete.cmd. This causes the file to be copied to c:\windows\setup\scripts\setupcomplete.cmd. When windows install is complete, if a file is present at that location, it is run under the SYSTEM account.

The problem is that this file remains even after the upgrade task sequence is totally complete. So if you then capture the image and deploy it to a real machine, it will see setupcomplete.cmd and run it after the deploy, instead of using the usual default Administrator account.

I imagine the presence of this file at c:\windows... is what causes the registry changes mentioned above. setupcomplete.cmd is only built to bootstrap an upgrade back into the MDT task sequence, and needs to be removed from c:\windows... when the task sequence is done running.

Knowing that the post-upgrade portion of the upgrade task-sequence runs as SYSTEM instead of Administrator via a very different mechanism than standard deployment is important, as there are then limits to what you can do. By default the sequence lets you install applications.. they need to be apps that are ok being installed by SYSTEM.

For now I've updated my local SetupComplete.cmd in my scripts directory to delete itself when it is done by changing the last for loop to this (there was also a typo in the for loop before preventing the exit echo):

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%d:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\setupcomplete.cmd ( 
del /q /f %%d:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\setupcomplete.cmd
echo %DATE%-%TIME% Exiting SetupComplete.cmd >> %WINDIR%\Temp\setupcomplete.log)
```

Comment: Discovered that my edit to SetupComplete.cmd is not sufficient. If you want to finish your task sequence with a shutdown, it means that SetupComplete.cmd will still be present and not removed until the next time you boot your machine. This may be minor in some cases, but causes a problem for me.

So I've moved to a manual step at the end of the task sequence to remove SetupComplete.cmd, and moved the cleanup code from SetupComplete.cmd to this new manual step.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this more and hitting issues due to running as the SYSTEM account, I started playing with avoiding running as the SYSTEM account. (One big problem is that if you want to shutdown at the end of the task sequence right after a reboot occurs, SYSTEM starts running too fast, and the call to shutdown in MDT fails.)

The idea is to instead use SetupComplete.cmd running as SYSTEM to simply bootstrap back into running the task sequence as the default Administrator.

There are a few wrinkles to implementing this. Namely, the synchronous commands that run from unattend.xml during a normal install do not run, so things like enabling admin, disabling uac for admin, disable user account page, disable async run once all have to be invoked manually. Beyond that, it is just a matter of setting the right registry entries by calls to PopulateAutoAdminLogon and SetStartMDT via a step in the task sequence after the OS upgrade is complete, and then performing a restart. This seems to work pretty well. The ideal way to do this would be to have the same script that calls PopulateAutoAdminLogon/SetStartMDT also parse unattend.xml and run those commands.

For some reason shell hiding does not work even though everything is set for it. My best guess is that the task sequence runner is doing this because IsOSUpgrade is set, but am not sure.

With this approach, SetupComplete.cmd is just responsible for a single bootstrap back into the task sequence, and the task sequence can delete it at the same time that it calls a script to do PopulateAutoAdminLogon/SetStartMDT

There is enough work to be done to fully polish this approach that I'll just workaround the one autologin issue for now, but it really does feel like a better way for MDT to work when doing upgrades. Hopefully they'll flesh it out in the future.